# Drawing lines and checkbox on same layer in Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt-creator

I want to design a GUI using Qt. That contains lines and check-boxs, which are connected to each other like this :

----------[ ]-----------

------[ ]---------[ ]-------------

(where dash represents line and [] is for check-box)

Lines are created dynamically. And selecting the check-box will disable the corresponding line. So basically the lines and check-box should be on same layer.

Any hint/link about the implementation is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what does your ASCII-picture means?

Comment: Here's the getting started guide. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/gettingstartedqt.html Here's how to place your widgets http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/layouts-basiclayouts.html And here's how to make your checkboxes do stuff. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a combination of [QFrame](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qframe.html#Shape-enum), [QCheckBox](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qcheckbox.html), and [QHBoxLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qhboxlayout.html). For something a little fancier, you could sub-class your own QWidget for each section and add them incrementally to a QVBoxLayout. Something like this...

```
class CheckLine : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CheckLine(int numboxes = 1, QObject* parent = 0) :
        QWidget(parent)
    {

        m_layout = new QHBoxLayout;
        m_layout->setSpacing(0);  //you can also set the margins to zero if need be
        setLayout(m_layout);

        QFrame* firstline = new QFrame();
        firstline->setFrameShape(QFrame::HLine);
        m_layout->addWidget(firstline);
        m_lines.append(firstline);

        for(int i = 0; i < numboxes; ++i)
            addBox();
    }

    void addBox()
    {
        QCheckBox* newbox = new QCheckBox("");  //add text here - or leave it blank if you want no label
        m_newbox->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
        m_layout->addWidget(newbox);
        m_boxes.append(newbox);

        QFrame* newline = new QFrame();
        newline->setFrameShape(QFrame::HLine);
        m_layout->addWidget(newline);
        m_lines.append(newline);

        /* link each checkbox to disable the line after it */
        connect(newbox, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), newline, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));
//      connect(newbox, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(setEnabled(bool)));  //use this instead if you want it to disable the entire row
    }

private:
    QHBoxLayout* m_layout;
    QList<QCheckBox*> m_boxes;
    QList<QFrame*> m_lines;
};
```

Then, create a widget with a QVBoxLayout and `new` a CheckLine, incrementing `numboxes` by 1 each time. Tweak the code if you want *any* checkbox to disable the entire line.

Comment: Thanks Phlucious that answers my question upto some extent. But I want a seamless joint between line and check-box. So that their should be no gap between line and check-box(I dont want any label also). Using SetSpacing() removes the left spacing.

Comment: I am using SetSpacing() for layout and SetFixedWidth() for check-box till the time I get some sophisticated solution.

Comment: That's pretty much how it's done. Removing the gap is simple enough. Just leave the check box's text blank and set its QSizePolicy to Fixed/Fixed, then set the layout's spacing to zero. See my edited sample code for that.